# Latent Dirichlet allocation

Tags: statistics, computer-science

I am currently trying to understand Blei, Ng and Jordan 2003 JMLR paper "latent Dirichlet allocation".

In section 3 page 997 I don't understand how to get to equation 3. The paper says "integrating over theta and summing over z". How come they push the summation over z after the product of the words? The sum of products and the product of the sums is not equal in general.

What allows, in that case, to push the sum inside the product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(There is a copy of the paper [here.](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~blei/papers/BleiNgJordan2003.pdf))

It's the distributive law.  Start with equation $(2)$ in the paper, which is 
$$
p(\theta,\,{\bf z},\,{\bf w}\mid \alpha,\,\beta)=
p(\theta\mid\alpha) \prod_{n=1}^N p(z_n\mid \theta)
p(w_n\mid z_n,\,\beta).
$$
Integrating over $\theta$ then gives
$$
p({\bf z},\,{\bf w}\mid \alpha,\,\beta)=\int 
p(\theta\mid\alpha) \prod_{n=1}^N p(z_n\mid \theta)
p(w_n\mid z_n,\,\beta) \, d\theta.
$$
Now, summing over ${\bf z}=(z_1,\ldots,z_N)$ gives
$$
p({\bf w}\mid \alpha,\,\beta)=\int 
p(\theta\mid\alpha) \sum_{z_1,\ldots,z_N} \prod_{n=1}^N p(z_n\mid \theta)
p(w_n\mid z_n,\,\beta) \, d\theta\ \ (*)
$$
and, using the distributive law in reverse, the sum of products can be changed into a product of sums:
\begin{eqnarray*}
&\ & \sum_{z_1,\ldots,z_N} \prod_{n=1}^N p(z_n\mid \theta)p(w_n\mid z_n,\,\beta)\\
&=& \sum_{z_1}\cdots\sum_{z_N} p(z_1\mid\theta)p(w_1\mid z_1,\,\beta)
\cdots p(z_N\mid\theta)p(w_N\mid z_N,\,\beta)\\
&=& \left(\sum_{z_1} p(z_1\mid\theta)p(w_1\mid z_1,\,\beta)\right)
\cdots
\left(\sum_{z_N} p(z_N\mid\theta)p(w_N\mid z_N,\,\beta)\right)\\
&=& \prod_{n=1}^N \sum_{z_n} p(z_n\mid\theta)p(w_n\mid z_n,\,\beta).
\end{eqnarray*}
Substituting this into $(*)$ gives equation $(3)$ in the paper.

Comment: The sum of product can be changed in a product of sum here because the product is independent of the z's? Each term in the product applies to a specific z_i. Right?

Comment: Yes; each term in the product depends on a specific $z_i$, so, for each $z_i$, the sum over $z_i$ can be moved so that it applies to only the appropriate term. It is like the identity $\sum_{k,\ell} c_k d_\ell=(\sum_k c_k)(\sum_\ell d_\ell)$.

Comment: Hum, there is something I must be missing here. Here is how I understand it. $$\prod_{n=1}^{N}\sum_{z_n}p(z_n|\theta)p(w_n|z_n, \beta )$$ $$=\prod_{n=1}^{N}\left(p(z_1|\theta)p(w_n|z_1, \beta )+p(z_2|\theta)p(w_n|z_2, \beta )+...+p(z_N|\theta)p(w_n|z_N, \beta )\right)$$ When expanding the product all the $p(w_i|z_j,\beta)$ where $i \neq j$ will be $0$ and cancel out. As a result all that's left are the terms for which $i=j$ leading to $$=\prod_{n=1}^{N}p(z_n|\theta)p(w_n|z_n,\beta)$$

Comment: Each $z_n$ can select any of the $k$ possible topics, so $$\prod_{n=1}^N \sum_{z_n} p(z_n\mid \theta)p(w_n\mid z_n,\beta)$$ $$=\prod_{n=1}^N (\theta_1\, p(w_n\mid z^1_n=1,\beta) + \theta_2\, p(w_n\mid z^2_n=1,\beta)+\cdots+\theta_k\, p(w_n\mid z^k_n=1,\beta)).$$